# How do I call this method?

Tags: java, methods, bufferedreader

For a project, I need to call the method **getBill** inside my main method. getBill returns an int value (bill), but when I declare it like:

```
getBill(qty);
```

I'm met with an error. I'm relatively new to using methods, did I declare the method itself correctly? Is there any way to do what getBill does without having to use a method?

This is the part of the code I'm working on where I need to call the method:

```
        while (true) {
            line = bc.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            billdata = line.split(",");
            accs = Integer.parseInt(billdata[0]);
            type = billdata[1];
            qty = Integer.parseInt(billdata[2]);
            company = billdata[3];


            if (accNo == accs) {
                System.out.println("Your RHY Telecom account has been found.");
                System.out.printf("%5s", accs);
                System.out.printf("%24s", qty);
                System.out.printf("%10s", type);
                System.out.printf("%20s", company);

                System.out.println("Your current charges are: ");

            }

        }
    }
```

This is the method itself:

```
    public static int getBill(int plan, int bill, int qty, String[] accountdata, String line) throws Exception {//getting details from text file number 2, then computing the bill
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/Account-Info-Final1.txt"));
        accountdata = line.split(",");
        plan = Integer.parseInt(accountdata[4]);
        bill = 0;
        int smslimit = Integer.parseInt(accountdata[5]);
        int calllimit = Integer.parseInt(accountdata[6]);
        double datalimit = Double.parseDouble(accountdata[7]);

        if (qty > smslimit) {
            bill = (qty * 2) + plan;
        } else if (qty > calllimit) {
            bill = (qty * 5) + plan;
        } else if (qty > datalimit) bill = (qty * 3) + plan;
        else if (qty <= smslimit || qty <= datalimit || qty <= calllimit){
                bill += plan;
            }
        return bill;
        }


    }
```

Comment: "I'm met with an error" What is the error?

Comment: What is the error? Error messages contain useful clues about what's wrong. So don't just say "there's an error" - try to understand what the error message is telling you. And add it to your question above.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a detailled description of your problem and a *minimal* example reproducing said problem.

Comment: I don't see that method in your code, so the correct answer to me is: not

Comment: the method says, "getBill() cannot be applied to: and it shows the expected parameters, which are int bill, int qty, int plan, String[] account data, and String line, then it shows the actual parameters, which is qty

Comment: Your method expects to get 5 parameters. You call it with only 1 parameter. Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: @TheLittleGreenFreshie Then you aren't passing all the data that is required to the method. If the method has 5 parameters, you need to pass all 5 pieces of data to it.

Comment: thank you! i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Think of a method as a mathematical function, with inputs and outputs.

Your getBill method declaration should only declare method arguments (that is, the comma-separated variables in parentheses) for things which the method needs as input.

Code which calls the getBill method does not need to supply a `plan` value as an input.  The method itself immediately overrides that value and ignores whatever value was supplied by the calling code.

You should remove `plan` from the method arguments, and instead declare it inside the method body:

```
int plan = Integer.parseInt(accountdata[4]);
```

The same is true for `bill`, `accountdata`, and `line`:

```
String line = bf.readLine();
String[] accountdata = line.split(",");
int plan = Integer.parseInt(accountdata[4]);
int bill = 0;
```

Once you remove all of them from your method signature, it will look like this:

```
public static int getBill(int qty)
```

…which will allow you to call the method as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your getBill method has 5 arguments, and you're passing in one argument.

Something like `getBill(1, 2, 3, new String[] { "Hello", "World" }, "Line");` would invoke the method, setting `plan` to 1, `bill` to 2, etcetera. You're setting `plan` to whatever the value of 1qty`is, and the other 4 arguments are still missing; you need to explicitly add them to your`getBill()` invocation.

NB: Sidenote, you're not closing your file resources, so this code will soon crash due to running out of resources. Look up 'try with resources' so you can safely open that file.